# ValueAnimator translate animiation

Tags: java, android

I need to create a translate animation through `ValueAnimator` to some specific `x` and `y` value, so I wrote the following code but its not work as I expected and throws `NullPointerExceptions` on `valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("x")` and `valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("y")`!

```
ValueAnimator translate = ValueAnimator.ofInt(viewX, endX, viewY, endY);
translate.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        int valX = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("x");
        int valY = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("y");

        updateViewLayout(mWindowManager, view2animate, valX, valY, null, null);
    }
});
translate.setDuration(1000);
translate.start();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue here is, you are trying to get the value for the property named "x" but you have not defined what is "x" and what are the values for it. So in your case, we need to define the limit of "x" and "y" properties.

So just replace

```
ValueAnimator translate = ValueAnimator.ofInt(viewX, endX, viewY, endY);
```

with

```
ValueAnimator translate = new ValueAnimator(); // Inititing ValueAnimator obj
translate.setValues(PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("x",viewX,endX), // set the limits of property "x"
                        PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("y", viewY,endY)); // setting the limits of property "y"
```

By this way, we can get fetch `valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("x") & valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue("y")` inside onAnimationUpdate method